# What is FAT (Functional Acceptance Testing)?

Tags: meta-tags

Can someone tell me the exact meaning of FAT (Functional Acceptance Testing) and when it would be used?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing